# how to pick most like items with PCA

Tags: r, pca

I run a PCA component analysis:

```
df <- tibble(green=c(1,5,6,5,4,3), blue=c(3,2,3,4,5,6), dark =c(1,1,2,4,4,3))
df.pca <- prcomp(as.matrix(df))
summary(df.pca)
```

[image: Result]

Now I need to find the two items out of the three, that look most alike.  I know the first two PCA explains 95% of the variance - and when I look at the table I can deduce that the most alike are blue and dark. But is there a systematic way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

PCA is very often visually inspected to find out which samples are closely related to each other.

You can make a plot to see that dark and blue are more alike:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(green=c(1,5,6,5,4,3), blue=c(3,2,3,4,5,6), dark =c(1,1,2,4,4,3))
df.pca <- prcomp(as.matrix(df))

plot_pca <- as.data.frame(df.pca$rotation) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "sample")
ggplot(plot_pca, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=sample))
```

(sorry, I didn't bother to adjust that the colours match your "samples").

[image]

Created on 2021-04-13 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)